# Is it possible to cluster particles and then resample each cluster?

Tags: filters, clustering, bootstrap-sampling

Is it possible to cluster particles (in the particle filter) and then resample each cluster separately? if yes, the resampling are done parallel?

Comment: Just in case this question gets no response, one might try the [statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com).